# Polymer.js databindings inside nested components

Tags: javascript, data-binding, polymer

I have a polymer element which is my parent element for my entire app. It performs ajax calls routinely and sets values according to the AJAX calls.

Within the polymer element I have a child element that needs to display one of these values dynamically.

Here is the child code:

```
<polymer-element name="main-status" attributes="auto">
    <template>
        <div id="status" flex>
            <div id="info" middle>
                <p>Robot is in {{ auto ? "AUTO" : "MANUAL T1" }} mode.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main-status.css">
    </template>
    <script src="main-status.js"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

It is used in the parent as such:

```
<main-status auto="{{statusAuto}}"></main-status>
```

And `{{statusAuto}}` is confirmed to change (between true and false). This change does not get reflected in the child element. I have similarly tried binding to global variables using the monostate pattern suggested on polymer's website, and I still have no success.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: The name of a Polymer element must contain a `-`. `mainstatus` is an invalid name. `main-status` is valid.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I'm sorry for the confusion, i removed my component name prefix's (which included dashes) for the purpose of this post. I'll insert some dashes into the post but i still have this issue. Thanks for letting me know!!

Comment: You can simplify your example to not use a ternary if, just add `{{auto}}` within the template to see if the value is updated in the child element.

Comment: The issue is there is a parent element that contains main-status (nested component), and main-status's attribute "auto" is bound to "statusAuto" in the parent element. But, when I update statusAuto, auto does not update, or the expression does not update.

Comment: I don't use Polymer with JavaScript only with Dart. In one of the previous questions someone mentioned that the Polymer element needs a field in JavaScript as well not only the `attributes` list (I doubt it but may be worth a try).

Comment: I tried printing just {{auto}} and it does indeed not update.

Comment: I've also added an auto property to the child elements javascript, and I am still experiencing the same thing. Thanks for the suggestions

Answer (score 0):

```
<main-status auto="{{statusAuto}}></main-status>
```

misses the closing quote - should be

```
<main-status auto="{{statusAuto}}"></main-status>
```

If that is only in the question not in your actual code try

```
<main-status auto="{{statusAuto}}">{{statusAuto}}</main-status>
```

and verify that `statusAuto` updates the value properly.